# show item position in list created with json during/after sorting using Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rubaxa-sortable

I have a list generated with json, and it's sortable with RubaXa/Sortable plugin.
I need to add the item position in the list while sorting the list. So when moving an item up or down the item position indicators will change.
I commented some lines with the issue.

Sortable function:

```
var listPos;
Sortable.create(list-group, {
  handle: '.driver',
  animation: 150,
  onMove: function (evt) {
    evt.dragged; 
    evt.draggedRect; 
    evt.related;
    evt.relatedRect;
    listPos = $(this).closest('.list-group').children('.list-group-item').index(this); // error finding the position in the list
    console.log(evt); // event is shown in the console
    console.log(listPos); // this is showing always -1 after the event
  }
});
```

The json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "item 1",
    "acr": "it1"
  },
  {
    "name": "item 2",
    "acr": "it2"
  },

  {
    "name": "item 3",
    "acr": "it3"
  },

  {
    "name": "item 4",
    "acr": "it4"
  }
]
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div id="printList" class="list-group">

  </div>
</div>
```

Parsing/Printing the json:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "/list.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
  showListPos = listPos; // showListPost in undefined
  var arr = JSON.parse(response);
  var i;
  var out = "";
  var drawPos = "<div class='position'>" + showListPos + "</div>"; //

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out += "<div class='list-group-item'>" +                 
            "<p>" + drawPos + "</p>"
            "<h3><span>" + arr[i].name + "</span>" +
            arr[i].acr +
            "</h3></div>";
  }
  out += "";
  document.getElementById("printList").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: did you try `$(this).closest('.list-group').index()`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, yes I did with the same result. output is -1

Answer (score 1):

to get the moved item position while moving it,you can use `onEnd` event instead `onMove`.in `onEnd` you can access position using `evt.newIndex`.check the below snippet

```js
Sortable.create(sortTrue, {
  group: "sorting",
  sort: true,
  onEnd: function(evt) {

    $(evt.item).parent().find('.list-group-item').each(function() {
      $(this).find('span').text($(this).index() + 1);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="result">Drage the list item to see position</div>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


  <!-- Latest Sortable -->
  <script src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>


  <!-- sort: true -->
  <div id="sortTrue" class="list-group">
    <div class="list-group-item"><span>1</span> foo</div>
    <div class="list-group-item"><span>2</span> bar</div>
    <div class="list-group-item"><span>3</span> baz</div>
    <div class="list-group-item"><span>4</span> qux</div>
    <div class="list-group-item"><span>5</span> quux</div>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Pavan, with onSort, onEnd... events the position is shown after dropping, I went with onMove to see if It was possible to show the current position while dragging.

Comment: current position means you want on which position the element will be dropped?

Comment: I meant before drop
But I just realized that having all the items position changing while dragging doesnt really worth it. I will go with onEnd... thanks...

Comment: This might works, I need to make some adjustments but you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks a lot